# How to perform faceting to group results by other fields in Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, faceted-search

I have a document mapping that looks like this:

```
_id : integer
title: string
category: string
country: string
```

Given a search by 'title' i would like to get the amount of results found in all categories and all countries, so something like

```
countries:
   USA: 38
   UK: 17
   ES: 5
   ....

categories:
   Animals: 6
   People:  772
   Objects: 87
   ....
```

Is it possible to do this in Elastic Search?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the standard behavior for faceting in Elasticsearch. Please refer to the [Elasticsearch Facets documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Alright! sorry i was unable to reproduce such behaviour as looks like i was using 'filter' instead of 'term' when asking for facets... thanks